# Changing the capstyle of ticks in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to use a round capstyle for ticks. I tried the following, but it does not work.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   
# better tick visiblity to check the capstyle
plt.rcParams.update({
           'figure.dpi': 150,
          u'xtick.major.size': 5.0,
          u'xtick.major.width': 2,
          })

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])

tl = ax.xaxis.get_ticklines()    
for i in tl:
    i.set_solid_capstyle('round')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, The reason that this does not work is that the tick marks are implemented single point lines with the ticks drawn as *markers*.

```
In [127]: [i.get_linestyle() for i in ax.xaxis.get_ticklines()]
Out[127]: 
['None',
 'None',
 'None',
 'None',
 'None',
 'None',
 'None',
 'None',
 'None',
 'None',
 'None',
 'None',
 'None',
 'None']
```

and

```
In [128]: [i.get_marker() for i in ax.xaxis.get_ticklines()]
Out[128]: [2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3]
```

see [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/markers_api.html#matplotlib.markers.MarkerStyle.markers) for mapping between ints -> shape, this is alternating 'tickup' and 'tickdown'.

This does let you do semi-cute things like

```
[i.set_marker('o') for i in ax.xaxis.get_ticklines()]
```

which gives [image: circles as ticks]

---

**If you use this, when upstream breaks it will be your problem**

To get what you want you can do reach well into the guts and set the capstyle on the tick marks:

```
for i in ax.xaxis.get_ticklines():
    # reach in and poke the guts 
    # USE AT YOUR OWN RISK
    i._marker._capstyle = 'round' 
    # this is not officially supported
```

note this uses not 1, but 2 private attributes and **will** be broken by the traitlet refactor that is coming in the next year (targeted for v2.1).  This will also be re-set to the hard-coded value of `'butt'` on `_recache` calls (which I don't remember off the top of my head exactly when that gets called).

I do not think you really want do to this:

[image: round cap ticks]

as it rounds both end of the ticks, not just the side pointed in (but then maybe an smaller tick sizes the rounded 'out' side will be hidden by the spine)

Comment: Thanks! Nice rounded one sided rounded markers would make another nice feature

Comment: @tillsten I can't stress enough though that you **should not actually do this** as there is a mid-term plan to break it!  I looked into using a `Path` to draw marker a half-rounded marker. I think it is possible, it will just require some finagling, and sorting out what 'width' and 'length' means in that case.

Comment: I will have a look at a possible path solution also. Btw is there a mpl setting to disable ticks when their location is exactly at the spine position?

Comment: Not that I know of, but I don't know the spine/tick/marker code super well.  Most of that code is very old and for the most part 'just works'.  I tend to know the code people report bugs against ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, this method doesn't work any more with the new `matplotlib` version. Is there another workaround?