# Rounded tick marks/ error bars in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hi I have looked for an solution to produce plots using matplotlib with rounded tick marks along the axes as well as with the error bars. Is this something that has been implemented in matplotlib, or would a work around need to be coded in to the "guts" of the library?

I've looked at old answers to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32539867/changing-the-capstyle-of-ticks-in-matplotlib) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40292875/change-capstyle-for-errorbars-in-matplotlib) but these answers suggest that these solutions would be phased out in future updates, which may have already happened. If so, is this included in any matplotlib documentation/ is there a workaronud? The above links have the same code that I want to write.

Comment: I gave a new solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40292875/change-capstyle-for-errorbars-in-matplotlib/55752418#55752418).

Comment: Thanks, very helpful for the error bars! Is the same thing comparable for the axis tick marks? I'll give it a shot at least.

Comment: The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32539867/changing-the-capstyle-of-ticks-in-matplotlib) about ticks is still valid, except the part where it says that traitlets will invalidate it in version 2.1 - because now is version 3.1 and traitlets are still far from being implemented.